# APEX 5 How to write selected Checkbox for each value in separated rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, checkbox, oracle-apex

i have a Checkbox Item in my Apex Form which gets everything from a LOV.
There is

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

source is my Database Column.

If i submit this form Apex writes me for example

```
ID:1 Checkbox_value: 2:3:5
```

in my table.

But i need it in separated rows. Like:

```
ID: 1 Checkbox_value: 2 
ID: 1 Checkbox_value: 3 
ID: 1 Checkbox_value: 5
```

I did not find any options at the Checkbox item. Can someone help me with a Idea?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Checkbox item most probably isn't alone, but belongs to some table which has some other columns. For example ("x" = checked, "o" = not checked):

```
ID  Name   Checkbox
--  ------ ---------
1   Little o x x o x
```

When you store that into the table and query it as

```
select id, name checkbox from your_table where id = 1;
```

you'll get

```
1   Little    2:3:5
```

as a result. So far so good, that's how it works.

Now you'd want to get

```
1   Little   2
1   Little   3
1   Little   5
```

as a result. Is that correct? If so, well, it's not how it works (as far as I can tell). Besides, it looks somewhat strange - creating one row for every checkbox value. Hm?

What to do? Why do you have one checkbox item for 5 different things? Consider creating 5 columns (in a table), which will then be reflected to Apex page as 5 separate checkbox items, i.e. you'd get - as a result of the `select` statement

```
ID  Name     CB1  CB2   CB3   CB4   CB5
1   Little   0    1     1     0     1
```

Another option might be creating a separate *detail* table for checkbox values (with a foreign key pointing to the *master* table which contains all other values), or a nested table (not a fan, personally).

Or, have it "as is", values stored as `2:3:5` and splitting them every time you want to create a relation to some other table (if that's what 2, 3 and 5 actually represent).

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot. Thanks for your great answer :) "What to do? Why do you have one checkbox item for 5 different things? Consider creating 5 columns (in a table)" The Problem is i actualy don't now how many Checkboxes i get. I have a select to another table for that. For now i have 5 Checkboxes but they can be more or less ... What i will now try is a PLSQL Loop. Maybe i can get the values and store them by PLSQL in separated rows ....

Comment: You're welcome. Well, if it is unknown how many checkboxes you'll have, consider creating a **detail table** which will store those options. Relation between that "new, detail table" and current "master table" would be a foreign key.

Comment: Yes i know. But how i can relate to the names behind the ID's?

Comment: Those won't be checkboxes, then, but *rows*. I'm thinking of an interactive grid or a tabular form (which enable you to use the "Add row" button and add as many rows as you need).

Comment: Mhhh that sounds like a good Idea. I will just check my loop and if this wont work i will tell you ;)